# iOS - Advance Animation With Swipe W/Velocity Of Swipe

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios

Basically I'm attempting a put your finger on the globe and spin it type function.

So all I really need to do is grab the direction of the swipe and velocity with a short timer (?500ms?)

So something like

```
While(swiping) {
   Get(pointTouched);
   swipeDirection = Calc(direction);
   swipeSpeed = Calc(speed);

   FramesToPlay = swipeSpeed * ConstantAmount;

   If(Direction == Backwards){
      FramesToPlay = FramesToPlay * -1;
   }

   Play(playAnimation, FramesToPlay);

   wait(500ms);
}
```

Anyone know anything like this? Or any pieces I can cobble together?

I have the Animation figured out it's just the details on this swiping that have me a touch confused.

Comment: I am here and trying to integrate everyone's comments and answers for which I am very thankful. As for your prior comment I'm also trying to rep up a bit so I can vote and give something back to those who helped.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could probably use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` which has a `velocityInView:` method.  I haven't tested this, but seems like it should work:

```
- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan
{
    if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        CGPoint vel = [pan velocityInView:self.view];
        [self doSpinAnimationWithVelocity:vel.x];
    }
}
```

In addition, when `pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerChanged`, you can have your globe turn along with the finger.

Answer (score 2):

Use the touchesBegan and touchesMoved delegates in the current UIView.  These delegates return xy locations and time stamps.  You can estimate the velocity of a touch or swipe by dividing the Pythagorean distance between touches by delta time, and get the angle from atan2(dy,dx).  You can also average or filter the velocity returned, by doing this over multiple touch events.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:  Create a subclass of `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`.  The purpose of this subclass would simply be to remember the very first and last `UITouch` objects that it receives in its `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method.  Everything else would be forwarded on to `super`.

When your recognizer triggers its action, the recognizer will be passed in as the `sender` parameter.  You can ask it for the initial and final touch objects, then use the `locationInView:` method and the `timestamp` property to figure out the velocity of the swipe (velocity = change in distance / change in time).

So it'd be something like this:

```
@interface DDSwipeGestureRecognizer : UISwipeGestureRecognizer 

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITouch * firstTouch;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITouch * lastTouch;

@end

@implementation DDSwipeGestureRecognizer
@synthesize firstTouch, lastTouch;

- (void) dealloc {
  [firstTouch release];
  [lastTouch release];
  [super dealloc];
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  [self setFirstTouch:[touches anyObject]];
  [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  [self setLastTouch:[touches anyObject]];
  [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

Then elsewhere you'd do:

```
DDSwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[DDSwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
[swipe setTarget:self];
[swipe setAction:@selector(swiped:)];
[myView addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
[swipe release];
```

And your action would be something like:

```
- (void) swiped:(DDSwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
  CGPoint firstPoint = [[recognizer firstTouch] locationInView:myView];
  CGPoint lastPoint = [[recognizer lastTouch] locationInView:myView];
  CGFloat distance = ...; // the distance between firstPoint and lastPoint
  NSTimeInterval elapsedTime = [[recognizer lastTouch] timestamp] - [[recognizer firstTouch] timestamp];
  CGFloat velocity = distance / elapsedTime;

  NSLog(@"the velocity of the swipe was %f points per second", velocity);
}
```

Warning: code typed in a browser and not compiled.  Caveat Implementor.

Comment: I'm not sure the touchesBegan and touchesEnded of the super class calls will work. I believe the UIGestureRecognizers don't belong to the responder chain. I might be wrong.

Comment: @nico They're not `UIResponder` objects, but the documentation for `UIGestureRecognizer` is very clear that these are the methods to override. Since we don't want to change the behavior of the swipe recognizer, we must forward the call on to `super`.

Comment: As the swipe consists of just one touch this is probably not going to work as apple guarantees that one touch is represented by the same object over and over again. So both `distance` and `elapsedTime` should be 0;